# search filter based on gidNumber in Openldap

Tags: openldap

I am new to openLDAP.

When I create a new user (using posixAccount), there is a field called GID Number. As this attribute is single valued. How can I add user to multiple groups or use search filter to get list of user in multiple groups based on GID number. Some one please suggest me on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The attribute *gidNumber* in *posixAccount* entries is just the primary group of the user (like in /etc/passwd).

You have to add *posixGroup* entries each with a separate unique *gidNumber*. Depending on the schema you want to use (RFC 2307 vs. RFC 2307bis) you populate attribute *memberUid* or *member* with a reference to the member entry. *memberUid* contains only the *uid* of the member and *member* would contain the DN of the member's entry.